# Check whether a limit has been applied to an ActiveRecordRelation

Tags: activerecord

I have a situation where I'm applying some criteria to an AR relation, but those criteria cannot be expressed in SQL. Users access this functionality similar to the following:

```
ar_relation = Model.all
filter = Filter.new
results_array = filter.filter(ar_relation, limit: 10, offset: 10)
```

This allows users to add their own criteria to `ar_relation` before applying the additional filtering.

I've run into the following problem: `Filter` will exclude rows from the result, so it needs to be aware of `limit` and `offset`. However, that is not obvious to users. If they add a `limit` or `offset` to `ar_relation` it breaks the processing in `Filter`.

My proposed solution is to have `Filter` check `ar_relation` for an `offset` or `limit` and throw an `ArgumentError` if one has been provided. However, from the the AR documentation I don't think it's possible to ask an AR relation what its current limit is. Is this possible?

Comment: Depending on what you actually want to accomplish, you may wish to remember the original values from `ar_relation` and reapply them later. `limit, offset = ar_relation.limit_value, ar_relation.offset_value`, `ar_relation = ar_relation.unscope(:limit, :offset)`, `filter.filter(ar_relation, limit: limit, offset: offset)`

Comment: Thanks! That was embarrassingly easy. It was a hard thing to Google, though: all the results I found were "how to apply a limit."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `#limit_value`

```
User.limit(4).limit_value
# => 4
```

As a hint for the future, I find this to be usually faster than digging through AR docs:

```
User.limit(4).public_methods.grep /limit/
```